# Using dplyr mutate_at with custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to take two variables from a table and divide them by a third variable and add these computations as two new columns. The `mutate_at` gets me very close but within the custom function, `f` below, I want to access another column in the data set. Any suggestions or alternate tidy tools approaches?

```
library(dplyr)
# this works fine but is NOT what I want
f <- function(fld){
  fld/5
}

# This IS what I want where wt is a field in the data
f <- function(fld){
  fld/wt
}

mutate_at(mtcars, .vars = vars(mpg, cyl), .funs = funs(xyz = f))

# This works but is pretty clumsy
f <- function(fld, dat) fld/dat$wt
mutate_at(mtcars, .vars = vars(mpg, cyl), .funs = funs(xyz = f(., mtcars)))

# This is closer but still it would be better if the function allowed the dataset to be submitted to the function without restating the name of the dataset

f <- function(fld, second){
  fld/second
}

mutate_at(mtcars, .vars = vars(mpg, cyl), .funs = funs(xyz = f(., wt)))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated version for dplyr 1.0.6:**

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(c(mpg, cyl), ~ . / wt))
```

Or this, which may be slower

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(c(mpg, cyl), `/`, wt))
```

**Previous answer:**

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(num, denom) num/denom

mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mpg, cyl), f, denom = quote(wt))
```

Although in this specific example, a custom function isn't needed.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(mpg, cyl), `/`, quote(wt))
```

Comment: I think this answer is just as clumsy as the examples in the question. Sure, you stripped out all the `.funs=funs...` mess, but that was not the point of the question. This is just two more ways to do exactly what the solutions in the question did: call the function and pass it a second argument inside `mutate()`. The key point in the question is to find a way to avoid having to pass that second argument.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear (and for the confrontational language). The denominator must be provided, but it is possible to do so without making it a function argument. I think this was the intent of the question because  of the statement “This IS what I want”, which is followed by a function with only one argument, and because the question already includes two working solutions that do the same thing that this answer does but with slightly different syntax. I think this answer would be improved by showing the option `f <- function(num) num/cur_data()$denom`. If you don’t mind, I will add it.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe something like this?

```
f <- function(fld,var){
    fld/var
}

mtcars %>%
    mutate_at(vars(mpg,cyl), .funs = funs(xyz = f(.,wt)))
```

**Edit (2020-08-24):**

As of second semester of 2020, with the launch of dplyr 1.0.0, `mutate_at` has been superseded by combining `mutate` with the `across` function:

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(across(c(mpg, cyl), ~ f(.,wt), .names = "{col}_xyz"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
mutate(mtcars, mpg2 = mpg / wt, cyl2 = cyl / wt)
```

Comment: That works for a couple of fields, but is not flexible and would be cumbersome with, say, 10 fields. If you changed your mind about the suffix ("2") you'd have to change it in several places etc.

Comment: Agreed, I guess i missed the crux of your question

Answer (score 1):

There is a `cur_data()` function that will help make the `mutate_at()` call more compact because **you will not have to specify a second argument to the function** that is being applied to each column:

```
f <- function(fld){
  fld / cur_data()$wt
}
mutate_at(mtcars, .vars=vars(mpg, cyl), .funs=funs(xyz = f))
```

Additional notes:

1. If you need the function to **reference a grouping variable**, use `cur_data_all()`
2. `mutate_at` is now superseded by `mutate(.data, across())`, so it would be better to do

```
mtcars %>% mutate(across(.cols=c(mpg, cyl), .fns=f, .names='{.col}_xyz'))
```